# How to assign user ranks based on their userpoints?

Tags: userpoints, 7

I am using the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [User points Nodes and Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_nc) modules to calculate user points when they publish an articles or comment on a node.

On these points I want to assign some rank to the user. Like for example

```
    Upto 100 – Junior Member
    100 to 300 – Senior Member
    300 + - Premier Member
```

Can someone give me some idea about this?

Comment: I didn't apply your answer so can't say anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems like a perfect usecase for the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer). It can be used in combination with the [userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module, though you'd use that combination by granting user points "after a goal is completed".

Here is a possible configuration for your specific case:

- Define 3 **goals** like so:

  - Junior Member
  - Senior Member
  - Premier Member
- To achieve *goal* "Junior Member", define the **Task(s)** to be completed. E.g.:

  - Publish 1 (or some other amount of) articles.
  - Post 1 (or some other amount of) comments.
- To achieve *goal* "Senior Member", define the **Task(s)** to be completed. E.g. publish 10 articles and post 20 comments.
- To achieve *goal* "Premier Member", define the **Task(s)** to be completed. E.g. publish 25 articles and post 50 comments.
- Write the appropriate rules, using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, to track process on completing the various tasks. Basically you'd only need 2 (extremely basic) rules, which would be triggered like so:

  - After publishing an article.
  - After posting a comment.

  Note that these very 2 rules can be re-used to measure progress on each of the 3 rules. If you want, you could expand these rules (with an extra rules action) to also assign userpoints, to implement your userpoints design you have in mind.

Refer to my answer to "[How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)" for way more details about the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module.

Note: Using [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) only requires typical administration tasks (configuration), though it does come with various hooks also for custom module development (if you want to).